# Scout / Scoutapp - how often are plugins and plugins with `counter()` run?

Tags: monitoring

I'm currently using [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/) for server monitoring purposes. However, I am confused about the frequency at which custom written plugins are run.

Does the frequency at which Scout plugins are run differ based on what functions are used in them? For instance, the `counter` function allows users to specify a rate of reporting (https://scoutapp.com/info/creating_a_plugin#counters). Whereas the `report` does not seem to have such an option. If a plugin mixes uses of `counter` with `:per => :second` and `:per => :minute`, along with calls to `report`, does that mean that the plugin is run once per second? What if the plugin only has `report` calls? What if the `:per` for all `counter` is set to `:minute`?

I couldn't find any official channel to ask Scout itself. If you could provide me with their tech support email or something similar, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I asked this question too hastily. For for the benefit of those who come up with the same questions in the future.

It turns out that, Scout runs as often as you decide it to, using cron. Refer to https://scoutapp.com/help#scout_agent for more information

So this applies to all the scout plugins you place in your own Scout plugin directories. The `:per` option for the `counter` function probably just does a division to obtain the rate.